# Variables as JavaScript Array Names

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

**Problem:** Trying to use 'dynamic' variables to access JSON/JavaScript arrays.
# EXAMPLE #
***Instead of...*** array1[ ] *or* array2[ ] *or* even array9000[ ]
***Somthing like...*** var my_array = 'array' + 'some generated number' ;
***Then just...*** my_array[ ] *or* my_array[some number]
*BUT this does'nt work...* (sollution **NOW** at bottom)

---

I have some PHP that's reading some directories PLUS there contents to create JSON arrays. The JSON arrays are named sequentially and they are storing image directories...
**Example JSON Array Names:** images0, images1, images2, etc...

```
    <?php
        $dir = opendir(getcwd());
        $num=0;
        while($folder = readdir($dir)) {
            if($folder !== '.' && $folder !== '..'){
                if (is_dir($folder)) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                    $folderCHILD = opendir($folder);
                    while($image = readdir($folderCHILD)) {
                        if($image !== '.' && $image !== '..'){
                            $images[]=$folder."/".$image;
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($folderCHILD);
                    echo 'images'.$num.' ='.json_encode($images);
                    unset($images);
                    echo '</script>';
                    $num++;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    ?>
```

Then I have some Javascript/Jquery that's 'attempting' to access these sequentially named JSON arrays through a click function. The function will create an image using the image directories stored in the JSON arrays.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('something').click(function() {
            var indexCURRENT = $(this).index();
            var ARRAY = 'images'+indexCURRENT;
            $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ src: ARRAY[some number]}).addClass("image").appendTo('body');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**^The Above Javascipt/Jquery Doesn't Work^**
But Thanks to **dev-null-dweller** this bit of code does work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gallery_link p').click(function() {
            var indexCURRENT = $(this).index();
            var ARRAY = 'images'+indexCURRENT;
            $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ src: window[ARRAY][some number]}).addClass("image").appendTo('body');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Difference?

```
.attr({ src: window[ARRAY][some number]})
```

Comment: try to distil down to its most basic form what you are trying to do.  rewrite a test bit of code to show it, there is too much information here to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: your numerated variables should be accessible in `window` object, accessed like array (`window['images1']`) so simply changing

```
{ src: ARRAY[1]}
```

to

```
{ src: window[ARRAY][1] }
```

should make it work.

Proper answer: use arrays / objects, it's simple as this:

```
<script>
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'images = [];';
$folderCHILD = opendir($folder);
while($image = readdir($folderCHILD)) {
    if($image !== '.' && $image !== '..' && $folder !=='resource'){
        $images[]=$folder."/".$image;
    }
}
closedir($folderCHILD);
echo 'images.push('.json_encode($images).');';
echo '</script>';
```

And then:

```
{ src: images[indexCUR][1] }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: Thanks for your input, I couldn't get your 'proper' answer to work (as of yet, I'm still at it) but your 'quick' fix works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do that in JS. You can't use a variable content as a variable name. This is feasible in php where you can do

```
$varname = 'x';

$$varname = "something";

print $x; //Prints "something"
```

but not in javascript. Just use a multidimensional array or a hash to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know it wasn't possible in javascript. @Gaet So... I've tried tinkering with multidimensional array but I didn't get too far cuz I couldn't think of creating the multidimensional array dynamically in javascript. Thanks to your info I'm gonna try setting it up within my PHP.